# ProjNet4GeoAPI calculates with mistake

Tags: c#, well-known-text

I need to convert from one geocs to another. I took wkt strings from https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4284/ and https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/.
Code is dead simple:

```
string ProjSk42 = " GEOGCS[\"Pulkovo 1942\",DATUM[\"D_Pulkovo_1942\",SPHEROID[\"Krassowsky_1940\",6378245,298.3]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]";
string ProjWgs84 = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"7030\"]], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"6326\"]], PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"8901\"]], UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"9102\"]], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"4326\"]]";

var wgs= ProjNet.IO.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(ProjWgs84) as GeographicCoordinateSystem  ;
var sk42 = ProjNet.IO.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(ProjSk42) as GeographicCoordinateSystem  ;
CoordinateTransformationFactory ctfac = new ();
ICoordinateTransformation trans = ctfac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems( wgs,sk42);   
 double[] fromPoint = { 66, 76 };
 double[] toPoint = trans.MathTransform.Transform(fromPoint);
```

I receive result, but it differs from https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=4284&x=76.0000000&y=66.0000000  for about ~70 meters in total (checked on map).
[image]
What can cause the problem?

**EDIT:**
If I use wkt string from https://epsg.io/4284 I have even worse result:
[image]

Comment: The epsg.io site is having also +towgs84 parameters. See https://epsg.io/4284 `TOWGS84[23.92,-141.27,-80.9,-0,0.35,0.82,-0.12]`.

Comment: Updated with towgs parameters

Comment: Current Proj 8.1.1 gives this result (from EPSG:4326 longitude-latitude ->) `76 66 76.0012456335389 65.999222661621 0`. How do these numbers compare?

Comment: Your result is correct. I can get it using cs2cs too, but I need to have it in C# code somehow. I guess ProjNet4GeoAPI is outdated?

Comment: spatial reference is not maintained any longer so it is several versions of the database behind which may make the differnce

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, args must be passed in correct order:

```
double[] fromPoint = { 76, 66 };
double[] toPoint = trans.MathTransform.Transform(fromPoint); 

var dif1 = toPoint[1] - 65.9992248;
var dif2 = toPoint[0] - 76.0012465;
```

[image]